# Multiline list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list

How I make multiline list comprehension in Python?
Something like:

```
[
  x for x in a:
    if check(x):
      ....
      #something multiline here
      ....
    else: 
      ....
      #something multiline here
      ....
]
```

Of course I know that I can to something like:

```
def f(x):
  if check(x):
     ....
  else: 
     ....
 return x

map(a,f)
```

But I want it without additional functions.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that you can not do it as you suggested.

It's far more readable when you name the function and use list comprehension or map function compared to what you have suggested

Comment: Ok let it be not a list comprehension, but it there something "like list comprehension" that produces a list basing on other list but without additional functions?

Comment: Only if you use lambda which still would be a expression rather than multi-line statements. I don't think python has this facility.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use `map` with `lambda` but as far as I know lambda functions cannot be multiline also

Answer (score 3):

You can't, in the way you're thinking; list comprehensions can only contain expressions, not statements.

Comment: Ok let it be not a list comprehension, but it there something "like list comprehension" that produces a list basing on other list but without additional functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiline list comprehensions and you can have `if` statements inside them, but the syntax is different from what you showed. I just tested this in the interpreter:

```
>>> tuple = ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j')
>>> list = [letter for letter in tuple
...         if (letter != 'a' and letter != 'b')]
>>> list
['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

You could also break it in other way, but the code will be a bit more messy:

```
>>> list = [letter for letter in
...     tuple if (letter != 'j' and letter != 'i')]
>>> list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

As the other guys pointed out, you might not use an `else` statement (couldn't make it work here). Besides, if the list comprehension start to grow too much it lose its conciseness (which I think it's strongest point).

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can do multiple nested list comprehensions. I do it all the time. Here is one example:

```
    A=[[[10 for y in range(3)],2][x<=3] for x in range(7)]
    print A
```

It generates a list with 4 times 2 and three sublists with 3 times 10 as elements.

```
    [2, 2, 2, 2, [10, 10, 10], [10, 10, 10], [10, 10, 10]]
```

As you can see, the outer list comprehension generates the 6 elements of the outer list, and the inner (first) list comprehension generates the inner 10s or the 2s, depending on whether x is smaller or equal to 3.

Comment: Why do you answer about nested comprehension if the question was about multiline comprehensions? How are these two topics related? (anyway thank you for the answer)